# Why can't I get previous url in controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my single page application project using AngujarJS 1.5.

At some point in my controller I need to get the previous URL.

I tried to use this code to get previous URL:

```
  var prevUrl = $document[0].referrer;
```

and this:

```
var prevUrl2 = document.referrer;
```

But `prevUrl` and `prevUrl2` are always empty.

When I use this code to go back:

```
$window.history.back();
```

It works fine.

As Umakant Mane advised:

I tried this:

```
dashboard.run(["$rootScope",
    function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('routeChangeStart', function (evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
            //routeHistory.push({ route: from, routeParams: fromParams });
            console.log('success', absOldUrl.templateUrl);
    }); 
}])
```

I expect to get a message in console but I don't get any message.

Any idea why `prevUrl` and `prevUrl2` is empty?

Comment: $routeChangeStart

Answer (score 0):

```
App.run(function($rootScope) {
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
       console.log('success', absOldUrl.templateUrl);

     });
 }); 

     Register this function in main index.js file where you register your angular app and assign this result to one global variable and use it
   Hope this may helps.
```

Comment: How do I use it in controller?

Comment: Set it in on $rootScope.previousUrl then can use in $scope in controller, or just write the goBack function in rootscope so can use anywhere

Comment: use doller($) symbol before routeChangeStart , check ur updated ans